How to calculate Zero Point Energy of an adsorbed molecule on a surface with quantum espresso?
I want to calculate zero point energy of a molecule that is adsorbed to a surface (by fixing the surface) with help of quantum espresso? I want a detailed explanation. I am not asking about the modes are imaginary or real I just want to get the phonon modes and the actual way to calculate the phonon modes.

Why do you want to fix the surface?

Does this answer your question? Zero point correction and free energy calculation with imaginary modes?

@PhilHasnip I want to calculate the ZPE for adsorbed molecule only. I don't want to consider the overall molecule with surface as it is time consuming and not that much useful in my case.
